# Smallness and Yoneda extension of categories

Tags: category-theory

I have read in Sheaves in Geometry and Logic by Maclane the following theorem:

> Given a small category and a functor $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{A}$ with $\mathcal{A}$ cocomplete we can construct the functor $R: \mathcal{A} \to Psh(\mathcal{C})$ given by $A \mapsto Hom(F(-),A)$. It follows then that there exists a functor $L: Psh(C) \to \mathcal{A}$ left adjoint to $R$.

What happens when $\mathcal{C}$ is not small? I want to use this theorem with $\operatorname{Spec}: Rng \to GSp$ where $GSp$ is the category of locally ringed spaces ( Geometric spaces in the notation of Demazure's book on algebraic groups).

Comment: The theorem is not applicable in the case where $\mathcal{C}$ is not small. However, if you read the definitions in [Demazure and Gabriel] carefully, you will see that they take care to use a two-universe setup in which you can apply the theorem.